# How to do discount for each product individually?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I need do some discount for each product individually, i know magento Promotion Cart inssue do that, but i need do bye custom attribute on product.

I added one custom attribute on my product, something like Discount Amout, where the shop owner will put something like 50%, and depending from Payment Method, it'll be applyed or no.

So, recapitulating...
I take any product from my store, and go to detail and there will have a field "Discount", i put 50% there.
This discount is only valid if the customer choose "Paypal" payment method.
So, on my checkout, i need check what payment method customer choose, and put the discount on product, but i need my review show "Discount -US$ 50", becouse i can change the price on that part. But can't put it on Discount field on review.

I need it so mutch, lose my day on that question.

Thks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it......
With this: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total?facebook=1

Ty ExcellenceMagentoBlog, saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Promotion - Shopping Cart Price Rule - Conditions - Cart Attribute - Payment method?

Comment: You are right man, i need do exactly this. BUT, at some easy way, like i said, i have discout amount, on my product. And with this is only i need to apply the discount on product. I need somekind of Cart Price Rule for each product, but with low process cost.